# Replace both whitespace and whitespace with comma, with a hyphen in JS?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to replace the following types:

```
Some Query String
Some Comma, Separated, Query String
```

With the following:

```
Some-Query-String
Some-Comma-Separated-Query-String
```

Any ideas on the regular expression for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
,?[ ]
```

Try this.Replace by `-`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/yR3mM3/14

```
var re = /,?[ ]/g;
var str = 'Some Query String\nSome Comma, Seperated, Query String';
var subst = '-';

var result = str.replace(re, subst);
```

Answer (score 3):

This should do what you want `/,?\s+/g`

```
'Some Comma, Seperated, Query String'.replace(/,?\s+/g, '-');
// Will produce: "Some-Comma-Seperated-Query-String"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just do this:

`'Some Comma, Seperated, Query String'.replace(/,?\s/g, '-');`

Hope that works for you. The question mark means one instance or less

Comment: @ankr answer uses the s+ to remove any amount of whitespace, prefixed by an optional comma. I would say that, if you want to ensure any amount of whitespace is removed, the s+ in that solution is better.